# How to display right japanese characters as output of a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using cp 932 and trying to get the output as i scripted:

```
@echo off
chcp 932
cls

echo a i u e o-ka ki ku ke ko-sa shi su se so-ta chi tsu te to-ha hi fu he ho-ma mi mu me mo-ya yu yo-ra ri ru re ro-wa wo n
echo.
echo あいうえお　きかくけこ　さしすせそ　たちつてと　なにぬねの　はひふへほ　まみむめも　やゆよ　らりるれろ　わをん
echo.
echo アイウエオ　カキクケコ　サシスセソ　タチツテト　ナニヌネノ　ハヒフヘホ　マミムメモ　ヤユヨ　ラリルレロ　ワヲン
pause>nul
```

but i get the following output:
[image: cmd prompt print]

> a i u e o-ka ki ku ke ko-sa shi su se so-ta chi tsu te to-ha hi fu he
>   ho-ma mi mu me mo-ya yu yo-ra ri ru re ro-wa wo n
>
> 縺ゅ＞縺・∴縺翫縺阪°縺上￠縺薙縺輔＠縺吶○縺昴縺溘■縺､縺ｦ縺ｨ縲縺ｪ縺ｫ縺ｬ縺ｭ縺ｮ縲縺ｯ縺ｲ縺ｵ縺ｸ縺ｻ縲縺ｾ縺ｿ繧繧√ｂ縲繧・ｆ繧医繧峨ｊ繧九ｌ繧阪繧上ｒ繧・
>
> 繧｢繧､繧ｦ繧ｨ繧ｪ縲繧ｫ繧ｭ繧ｯ繧ｱ繧ｳ縲繧ｵ繧ｷ繧ｹ繧ｻ繧ｽ縲繧ｿ繝√ヤ繝・ヨ縲繝翫ル繝後ロ繝弱繝上ヲ繝輔・繝帙繝槭Α繝繝｡繝｢縲繝､繝ｦ繝ｨ縲繝ｩ繝ｪ繝ｫ繝ｬ繝ｭ縲繝ｯ繝ｲ繝ｳ

How to display the right characters?

Comment: maybe codepage 65001. check also your file encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem. As you can see, I'm on (Central European) Windows with Latin script:

[image: script result]

You need to **save the script using right encoding**:

[image: script using 932 encoding]

Moreover, **Windows itself switch to right font** (my default `cmd` font is set to *Courier New* with no CJK script):

[image: font]

Comment: It worked! Thanks. But i code via windows text file or just editing direct on batch file, so, i've tried to "save as" in another encoding, but didn't work. Then i used Notepad++ to change the encoding and save it. Is there anyway to do it whitout a code editor?

Comment: Windows Notepad's "_Save_" or "_Save As_". offers (some _UTF_ encodings and) co-called **ANSI** encoding. It's **system-wide** value obtained from `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v ACP`.  AFAIK, you need a code editor (like _Visual Studio Code_ or _N++_)…

Answer (score 1):

You can convert text to `Base64` and Decode it in Vbscript to show text.

Save whole code bellow as a `.vbs` and run it.(Don't run it via `cscript` or `wscript`).

Try my way :

```
Str="44GC44GE44GG44GI44GK44CA44GN44GL44GP44GR44GT44CA44GV44GX44GZ44Gb44Gd44CA44Gf44Gh44Gk44Gm44Go44CA44Gq44Gr44Gs44Gt44Gu44CA44Gv44Gy44G144G444G744CA44G+44G/44KA44KB44KC44CA44KE44KG44KI44CA44KJ44KK44KL44KM44KN44CA44KP44KS44KT"
St="44Ki44Kk44Km44Ko44Kq44CA44Kr44Kt44Kv44Kx44Kz44CA44K144K344K544K744K944CA44K/44OB44OE44OG44OI44CA44OK44OL44OM44ON44OO44CA44OP44OS44OV44OY44Ob44CA44Oe44Of44Og44Oh44Oi44CA44Ok44Om44Oo44CA44Op44Oq44Or44Os44Ot44CA44Ov44Oy44Oz"
'===========================================================================
Function Base64Decode(ByVal vCode)
 Set oNode = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0").CreateElement("base64")
 oNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
 oNode.text = vCode
 Base64Decode = Stream_BinaryToString(oNode.nodeTypedValue)
 Set oNode = Nothing
End Function

Function Stream_BinaryToString(Binary)
 Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BinaryStream.Type = 1
 BinaryStream.Open
 BinaryStream.Write Binary
 BinaryStream.Position = 0
 BinaryStream.Type = 2
 BinaryStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
 Stream_BinaryToString = BinaryStream.ReadText
 Set BinaryStream = Nothing
End Function
WSH.Echo "a i u e o-ka ki ku ke ko-sa shi su se so-ta chi tsu te to-ha hi fu he ho-ma mi mu me mo-ya yu yo-ra ri ru re ro-wa wo n"&vblf&Vblf&Base64Decode(Str)&vblf&Vblf&Base64Decode(St)
```